# Webbrowser control sometimes doesn't fully load a page, but document_completed event is fired

Tags: c#, facebook, html-agility-pack

I have a scraper that scrapes data from three kinds of websites.
One of those websites (Facebook) have multiple page formats that needs to be scraped.

While two websites work fine, one particular Facebook page layout refuses to work or work very strangely. (for other Facebook page layouts I haven't noticed this behavior)

I am reading each link from a file and load into webbrowser control, I wait until each page fully loads (using AutoResetEvent) and then after it loads, I send pages html to other class from the webbrowser_Document_Completed event to do the scraping.

The problem here is that sometimes page is not fully loaded and sometimes it fully loads.
In both cases webcontrol_Document_Completed is fired.
When the page fully loads, it works just fine.
I debugged and indeed, page is not fully loaded and data is missing.
It can pass 4-5 times in a row to fully load the page and then suddenly stops. (random pattern)

I don't know anymore where to look for the culprit.

I thought that my code is not ok so I created new test project that just loads that page and same problem occurs.
So maybe the page is the problem because I also saw that when it doesn't work, needed data is commented.
Maybe some scrape protection...

Page in question is: https://www.facebook.com/pages/Childrens-Dental-Care/76095547112?v=info&viewas=0 and needs to scrape right side of the page where is Joined Facebook, Hours and Parking.
It's //td[@class='data'] element that I need.

If you have any idea that might point to solving this issue...

Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Facing a similar issue with Netflix.

Comment: @cvocvo Since it was a while ago, I cannot remember for certain what it was, but I think it was Facebooks random commenting and because of it, that element wasn't fetched and program exited at checking for null and that seemed like it wasn't loaded. I worked around that by removing <!-- and --> in html. Hope that helps in any way.